# Omitting constructor arguments in Haskell case statements

Tags: haskell

Omitting function arguments is a nice tool for concise Haskell code.

```
h :: String -> Int
h = (4 +) . length
```

What about omitting data constructor arguments in case statements. The following code might be considered a little grungy, where `s` and `i` are the final arguments in `A` and `B` but are repeated as the final arguments in the body of each case match.

```
f :: Foo -> Int
f = \case
     A s -> 4 + length s
     B i -> 2 + id i
```

Is there a way to omit such arguments in case pattern matching? For constructors with a large number of arguments, this would radically shorten code width. E.g. the following pseudo code.

```
g :: Foo -> Int
g = \case
     {- match `A` constructor -> function application to A's arguments -}
     A -> (4 +) . length
     {- match `B` constructor -> function application to B's arguments -}
     B -> (2 +) . id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GHC extension `RecordWildCards` lets you concisely bring all the fields of a constructor into scope (of course, this requires you to give names to those fields).

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase, RecordWildCards #-}

data Foo = Foo {field1, field2 :: Int} | Bar {field1 :: Int}

baz = \case
    Foo{..} -> 4 + field2
    Bar{..} -> 2 + field1

-- plus it also "sucks in" fields from a scope
mkBar400 = let field1 = 400 in Bar{..}
```

`

Comment: You can also just write `Foo {}` or `Bar {}` to match on the constructor, without needing any extension. Note that this works even if you don't use record syntax for the datatype.

Comment: @kosmikus If record syntax isn't used, how would I place the constructor arguments in the correct places on the right hand side of the arrow?

Comment: I had never seen that it could "suck in" fields from the current scope, that could be really useful!

Comment: @RobStewart You wouldn't.

Comment: @RobStewart If you use `{}`, you can't refer to the arguments. Sometimes, you only want to distinguish on the constructor, and writing `Foo {}` can be easier than writing `Foo _ _ _ _`. But it's not a general solution to your question, which is why I just added it as a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can always refactor case statements on constructors into a single function so that from then on you only pass your concise function definitions as arguments to these specific functions. Allow me to illustrate.

Consider the `Maybe a` datatype:

```
 data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Should you now need to define a function `f :: Maybe a -> b` (for some fixed `b` and perhaps also `a`), instead of writing it like

```
 f Nothing = this
 f (Just x) = that x
```

you could start by first defining a function

```
 maybe f _ Nothing = f
 maybe _ g (Just x) = g x
```

and then `f` can by defined as `maybe this that`. Pretty much as what happens with all the familiar recursion patterns.

This way you're effectively refactoring out case statements. The code gets arguably cleaner and it does not require language extensions.